# Solving the complex equation $\cos^2{z}=-1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have tried to solve equation $\cos^2{z}=-1$ in two different ways and I found something curious and confusing that I can't understand yet. I explain below the two ways I have tried to solve this equation.

**First way to solve:**

$\cos^2{z}=-1$ implies that $\cos{z}=\sqrt{-1}=\{\pm i\}$.

Now, we solve $\cos{z}=i$ using the exponential expression of $\cos{z}$, that is, $\cos{z}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$. We obtain the equation $e^{2iz}-2ie^{iz}+1=0$ and we solve to conclude that $e^{iz}=(1\pm\sqrt{2})i$. Now, taking the logarithm, we obtain these two results: $z_1=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i\ln{(1+\sqrt{2})}$ and $z_2=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i\ln{(\sqrt{2}-1)}$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We solve $\cos{z}=-i$ in a similar way and we obtain these two other solutions: $z_3=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i\ln{(-1+\sqrt{2})}$ and $z_4=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i\ln{(1+\sqrt{2})}$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, working out in this way, we have obtained four solutions to the equation $\cos^2{z}=-1$: $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ and $z_4$.

**Second way to solve:**

In this case, we substitute directly $\cos{z}$ by $\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ in $\cos^2{z}=-1$ and we obtain this equation: $e^{4iz}+6e^{2iz}+1=0$. If we solve this equation we obtain: $e^{2iz}=-3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$. Now, taking the logarithm, we obtain these two results: $\tilde{z}_1=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\frac{i}{2}\ln{(3-2\sqrt{2})}$ and $\tilde{z}_2=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\frac{i}{2}\ln{(3+2\sqrt{2})}$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Conclusion**

We can observe that we obtain four solutions in the first way and two solutions in the second way. We can also observe that there is a relation between some solutions of the two ways of work: $z_1=\tilde{z}_1$ and $z_3=\tilde{z}_2$.

**Question**

I don't understand what is happening here, why do we obtain different solutions?

I think that the error could be in the second way to work out, but I haven't figured out yet what is wrong in the reasoning.

Does anybody know something about what is happening here, please? Any kind of help will be very welcomed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand how you are counting those solutions. You claim that you get four solutions using the first method and only two using the second one. But, in fact, you get infinitely many solutions in both cases.

Comment: your $z_1,z_4$ together (as an infinite set) give the infinite set $\tilde{z}_2$ as $\pm \pi/2 +2k \pi$ is the same $\pi/2+m\pi$ as a set; same with the others (check a few small examples of $k$ and see the corresponding $m$ to convince yourself if you cannot see that directly as $m$ is even if you choose the plus sign in $\pm \pi /2$ and $m$ odd if you choose the minus sign)

Comment: Note that $3-2*\sqrt{2}$ is equal to $(1-\sqrt{2})^{2}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, José Carlos Santos. I am sorry, you are right, we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers, Conrad and Salcio! They have been very useful and I have already understood it; I see it very clear now.